# Count occurrences of particular name in Json Array

Tags: c#, .net, json

I want to count number of occurrences in Json Array returned by an API
my data is

```
data = [
  {"id":"1939317721","pauseReason":"DISPLAY","DeptName":"Account"},
  {"id":"1939317722","pauseReason":"DISPLAY","DeptName":"Admission"},
  {"id":"1939317723","pauseReason":"DISPLAY","DeptName":"Account"},
  {"id":"1939317724","pauseReason":"DISPLAY","DeptName":"Account"},
]
```

As a result I want

```
res = {"account":3,"admission":1}
```

So how can I get number of occurrences of `DeptName` in result in key values pair?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  A good choice is https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a class like:

```
class Foo {
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string PauseReason {get;set;}
   public string DeptName {get;set;}
}
```

then with something like Json.NET:

```
var foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo[]>(json);
```

and then LINQ:

```
var grouped = foos.GroupBy(x => x.DeptName);
foreach(var grp in grouped)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Key}: {grp.Count()}");
}
```

If you are trying to format that as JSON, then:

```
var map = grouped.ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(map);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Worked like a miracle.